# CPP: Macros in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm using bindings-DSL to help deal with some boilerplate in FFI declarations. But I find myself declaring groups of related functions that differ by only a couple of textual elements, and I'd really rather declare these with a macro. CPP or CPPHS seems the ideal choice for this, but I can't find any examples to its usage in the context of Haskell.

I've put this into what I approximately expect to work from my knowledge of C macros:

```
#define declare_vector_funcs (t, tn, ct) \ 
    #opaque_t vector_##t \
    #ccall create_std_vector##tn , IO (Ptr <vector_##t##>) \
    #ccall carray_to_std_vector##tn , Ptr ct -> CSize -> IO (Ptr <vector_##t##>) \
    #ccall std_vector##tn##_to_carray , Ptr <vector_##t##> -> IO (Ptr ct) \
    #ccall std_vector##tn##_length , Ptr <vector_##t##> -> IO CSize
```

Essentially, I'd like to define a foreign (opaque) type and 4 foreign functions upon expanding this macro. However, this does not work as it reads everything subsequent to the argument list as GHC pragmas, and fails.

I've already tried a couple different iterations of this, such as messing with spacing and putting everything on one line (wrapped in parentheses to distinguish separate macro calls).

How can I fix this to work? Answers that drop the bindings-DSL usage in favor of a direct translation are fine, but I definitely don't want to write all this out by hand.

I would also very much appreciate a few examples of this kind of CPP usage.

Here's the error message I get if I remove the space between the macro name and argument list:

```
CPP.hsc:13:39: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
compiling dist/build/Foreign/CPP_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
command was: /usr/bin/g++ -c dist/build/Foreign/CPP_hsc_make.c -o dist/build/Foreign/CPP_hsc_make.o -fno-stack-protector -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=708 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS=1 -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH=1 -Dlinux_HOST_OS=1 -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH=1 -Iinclude/ -fpermissive -std=c++11 -fPIC -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.2/bindings-DSL-1.0.21/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.2/base-4.7.0.0/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.2/integer-gmp-0.5.1.0/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.2/include -I/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.2/include/
```

With the space, I get a much longer error message:

```
dist/build/Foreign/CPP.hs:1:16:
    unknown flag in  {-# OPTIONS_GHC #-} pragma: tn,
dist/build/Foreign/CPP.hs:1:16:
    unknown flag in  {-# OPTIONS_GHC #-} pragma: ct)
dist/build/Foreign/CPP.hs:1:16:
    unknown flag in  {-# OPTIONS_GHC #-} pragma: #opaque_t
dist/build/Foreign/CPP.hs:1:16:
    unknown flag in  {-# OPTIONS_GHC #-} pragma: vector_##t
```

And this continues for every token. I'm fairly certain this just means the space shouldn't be included, but I'm not really sure what's going on.

---

EDIT:

### New info.

I swapped methodology and I'm trying to generate the final foreign imports directly. The macro (I'll paste in a sec) passes the preprocessor with a couple of warnings, but actually trying to use the macro doesn't yet work:

```
#define declare_vector_funcs(t, tn ,ct) \
    data C'vector_##t = C'vector_##t \
    foreign import ccall "create_std_vector##tn" c'create_std_vector##tn :: IO (Ptr C'vector_##t) \
    foreign import ccall "carray_to_std_vector##tn" c'carray_to_std_vector##tn :: Ptr ct -> CSize -> IO (Ptr vector_##t) \
    foreign import ccall "std_vector##tn##_to_carray" c'std_vector##tn##_to_carray :: Ptr vector_##t -> IO (Ptr ct) \
    foreign import ccall "std_vector##tn##_length" c'std_vector :: Ptr vector_##t -> IO CSize
```

At the usage site, I'm trying to use it like:

```
#declare_vector_funcs int , i , CInt
```

To match the equivalent declaration on the C side. I expect it to generate a block that looks like:

```
data C'vector_int = C'vector_int 
foreign import ccall "create_std_vectori" c'create_std_vectori :: IO (Ptr C'vector_int) 
foreign import ccall "carray_to_std_vectori" c'carray_to_std_vectori :: Ptr CInt -> CSize -> IO (Ptr vector_int) 
foreign import ccall "std_vectori_to_carray" c'std_vectori_to_carray :: Ptr vector_int -> IO (Ptr CInt) 
foreign import ccall "std_vectori_length" c'std_vector :: Ptr vector_int -> IO CSize
```

But instead I get an error:

```
CPP.hsc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
CPP.hsc:22:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
CPP.hsc:22:37: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
CPP.hsc:22:41: error: ‘CInt’ was not declared in this scope
CPP.hsc:22:45: error: ‘hsc_declare_vector_funcs’ was not declared in this scope
CPP.hsc:23:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
CPP.hsc:23:39: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
CPP.hsc:23:43: error: ‘CFloat’ was not declared in this scope
CPP.hsc:24:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
CPP.hsc:24:40: error: ‘d’ was not declared in this scope
CPP.hsc:24:44: error: ‘CDouble’ was not declared in this scope
```

So I obviously need to add `import Foreign.C` to the top, but even so, there's a deeper issue -- I can't treat these tokens as meaningless like I'd like to, something is trying to actually interpret them. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are presumably using `-XCPP`, right? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yep, it's at the top of the file. I'll edit the OP with a part of the error message, the actual one is too long to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't quite possible, I don't think, when you define a macro in a `hsc` file it will get inlined into your generated `.hs` file, and if that macro calls `.hsc` macros.. well those won't be available anymore. The best you can do:

```
module Test where

import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types

data T
data Tn
data Ct

#opaque_t vector_T
#ccall create_std_vectorTn , IO (Ptr <vector_T>)
#ccall carray_to_std_vectorTn , Ptr Ct -> CSize -> IO (Ptr <vector_T>) 
#ccall std_vectorTn_to_carray , Ptr <vector_T> -> IO (Ptr Ct) 
#ccall std_vectorTn_length , Ptr <vector_T> -> IO CSize
```

If your C compiler knows where to find `bindings.dsl.h` then you should include it at the top; mine doesn't so I compile with `hsc2hs --include=<path-to-bindings.dsl.h> test.hsc`. This produces the following file:

```
{-# LINE 1 "test.hsc" #-}
module Test where
{-# LINE 2 "test.hsc" #-}

import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types

data T
data Tn
data Ct

data C'vector_T = C'vector_T

{-# LINE 11 "test.hsc" #-}
foreign import ccall "create_std_vectorTn" c'create_std_vectorTn
  :: IO (Ptr C'vector_T)
foreign import ccall "&create_std_vectorTn" p'create_std_vectorTn
  :: FunPtr (IO (Ptr C'vector_T))

{-# LINE 12 "test.hsc" #-}
foreign import ccall "carray_to_std_vectorTn" c'carray_to_std_vectorTn
  :: Ptr Ct -> CSize -> IO (Ptr C'vector_T)
foreign import ccall "&carray_to_std_vectorTn" p'carray_to_std_vectorTn
  :: FunPtr (Ptr Ct -> CSize -> IO (Ptr C'vector_T))

{-# LINE 13 "test.hsc" #-}
foreign import ccall "std_vectorTn_to_carray" c'std_vectorTn_to_carray
  :: Ptr C'vector_T -> IO (Ptr Ct)
foreign import ccall "&std_vectorTn_to_carray" p'std_vectorTn_to_carray
  :: FunPtr (Ptr C'vector_T -> IO (Ptr Ct))

{-# LINE 14 "test.hsc" #-}
foreign import ccall "std_vectorTn_length" c'std_vectorTn_length
  :: Ptr C'vector_T -> IO CSize
foreign import ccall "&std_vectorTn_length" p'std_vectorTn_length
  :: FunPtr (Ptr C'vector_T -> IO CSize)

{-# LINE 15 "test.hsc" #-}
```

---

So looks like defining your own macro is the way to go:

mymacro.h

```
#define hsc_declare_vector_funcs(t,tn,ct)\
  hsc_opaque_t(vector_##t)\
  hsc_ccall(create_std_vector##tn ,IO (Ptr <vector_##t>))\
  hsc_ccall(carray_to_std_vector##tn , Ptr ct -> CSize -> IO (Ptr <vector_##t>)) \
  hsc_ccall(std_vector##tn##_to_carray , Ptr <vector_##t> -> IO (Ptr ct)) \
  hsc_ccall(std_vector##tn##_length , Ptr <vector_##t> -> IO CSize)
```

test.hsc

```
module Test where

#include "mymacro.h"

import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types

#declare_vector_funcs int, i, CInt
```

test.hs

```
module Test where

import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.Types

data C'vector_int = C'vector_int
foreign import ccall "create_std_vectori" c'create_std_vectori
  :: IO (Ptr C'vector_int)
foreign import ccall "&create_std_vectori" p'create_std_vectori
  :: FunPtr (IO (Ptr C'vector_int))
foreign import ccall "carray_to_std_vectori" c'carray_to_std_vectori
  :: Ptr CInt -> CSize -> IO (Ptr C'vector_int)
foreign import ccall "&carray_to_std_vectori" p'carray_to_std_vectori
  :: FunPtr (Ptr CInt -> CSize -> IO (Ptr C'vector_int))
foreign import ccall "std_vectori_to_carray" c'std_vectori_to_carray
  :: Ptr C'vector_int -> IO (Ptr CInt)
foreign import ccall "&std_vectori_to_carray" p'std_vectori_to_carray
  :: FunPtr (Ptr C'vector_int -> IO (Ptr CInt))
foreign import ccall "std_vectori_length" c'std_vectori_length
  :: Ptr C'vector_int -> IO CSize
foreign import ccall "&std_vectori_length" p'std_vectori_length
  :: FunPtr (Ptr C'vector_int -> IO CSize)
```

Comment: Yea, this is what I'm currently doing -- but I'm working on making c++ vectors available and so I need a way to declare the necessary functions in a block without specifying each one by hand. I guess I'll change the macro to generate these final bindings rather than the intermediary bindings-DSL macros.

Comment: Made some edits with a progress update on the new situation based on your answer.

Comment: @acomar It looks like we are close. Check my update.

Comment: I edited your post with the fix for the ct issue, check the revision history. This still leaves the issue of getting the generated declarations to match the declarations on the C side like I mentioned in my edit in the OP.

Comment: @acomar Thanks for the fix. The macro generates the exact same code as manually writing it out as I did in my original answer and you were doing as well. Which issue do you mean?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. I'm trying to get the macro to expand something like the following: `#declare_vector_funcs int, i, CInt`, so that the functions match on the C and Haskell sides. I'm stuck at the same point in the OP :/

Comment: @acomar That would generates things like `c'std_vectortn_to_carray :: Ptr C'vector_int -> IO (Ptr CInt)` which seems like it would work just fine.

Comment: Your answer generates `c'std_vectorTn_to_carray :: Ptr C'vector_T -> IO (Ptr Ct)`. I'd like to generate `c'std_vectori_to_carray :: Ptr C'vector_int -> IO (Ptr CInt)` as well as `c'std_vectorf_to_carray :: Ptr C'vector_float -> IO (Ptr CFloat)` and many more. I'm just using one specific example.

Comment: @acomar It looks like there was a bug, forgot a `##`.

Answer (score 2):

The following example compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

#define MYMACRO 3
#define MAX(a,b) (if ((a) < (b)) \
              then (b) \
              else (a))

main = print $ show (MAX(MYMACRO,4) :: Int)
```

I need the parens around the code macro so that the following will (also) work:

```
main = print $ show MAX(MYMACRO,4)
```

Comment: Ok this example makes me think the issue is that I'm trying to expand to other macros. I'll try a few different methods of escaping to see if that resolves anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with bindings-DSL, take a look at how it was done in [bindings-gobject](https://github.com/Yuras/bindings-gobject/blob/master/bindings.dsl.gobject.h). You have to use the hsc_* macros.